# Flutter or Dart: How to I get device information such as CPU count, total memory and storage, etc

Tags: dart, flutter, system-information

Using Flutter, I would like to get device information details such as CPU count, bitness, Total Memory, Total device storage, etc. Similar to apps one can get on the App stores.

I looked at device_info package, but that does not cover it. I also looked at system_info (which is pretty good, seems abandoned), but only works on Android since it's using Linux shell commands to get the info. I would also like it to work for iOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could maybe use some native code to get this information and then use it in your flutter app

Answer (score 2):

The information is now available under the package: [system_info2](https://pub.dev/packages/system_info2) since [system_info](https://pub.dev/documentation/system_info/latest/) is discontinued, with this you can easily get:

1. KernelArchitecture
2. Kernel bitness
3. Kernel name
4. Kernel version
5. Operating system name
6. Operating system version
7. User directory
8. User id
9. User name
10. User space bitness

Comment: this package only works on Android?

Comment: If you take a look at the package you'll notice it's supported platforms: PLATFORM: ANDROID IOS LINUX MACOS WINDOWS

Comment: tested out on physical iOS devices, but its giving me Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem error

Comment: Check the package's issues on GitHub to see if exists already or file one if there's none related to your problem.

Comment: It's not supported on iOS

Answer (score 1):

Add this package to your pubspec.yaml: `system_info: ^0.0.15`,
read more about it here : [system_info](https://pub.dev/packages/system_info/versions/0.0.15).
The docs says: Provides easy access to useful information about the system (architecture, bitness, kernel, operating system, CPU, user).

Comment: Unfortunately `system_info` doesn't support iOS but it works for MacOs

Comment: For now (2022-04-14), the package is discontinued for 9 months.