# Dart or Flutter: how do I get the num of processor cores?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the make a multi threaded application and spawn 1 isolate per core. How can I know the number of processor cores in Dart language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways:

- The easiest one is import `dart:io` and calling `Platform.numberOfProcessors`
- The second way is using the pub library `system_info`, as explained on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859730/flutter-or-dart-how-to-i-get-device-information-such-as-cpu-count-total-memory).

On my personal tests I found the `dart:io` library more precise when dealing with multi-core processors.
The `system_info` library returned 4 processors while `dart:io` library returned 8 cores on my Windows pc with a Intel Core i7-8550U CPU (it has 4 cores but 8 threads).

Comment: Core and (hyper) threads are different things: core is a physical hardware. Hyper thread is code running in sliced multithreading on a single core. In practice, since most of the time CPU is not busy running code (but waiting for hardware, including ALU, RAM, etc.), hyper thread performance is near 2x core performance. So, if you are asking how much CORES your CPU have? 4. How much HYPER THREADS your CPU can run at the same time? That's 8. Also, consider that most mobile phones have slow and fast cores (that's their way of saving battery)